# unable to get contents of web api json response, returning blank

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm a complete beginner with front end programming; however, I'm seasoned in backend c# (non web-stuff).

I've got 2 visual studios open. One is serving up web api, and the other one is consuming the web api.

**How do I read and display json from a remote source?**

When trying to read one of the APIs, the page is showing nothing.

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Hello AngularJS</title>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/GbyG.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="GbyG">

<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in greeting">
        <td>{{data.FirstName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

**GbyG.js**

```
'use strict';

app.controller('GbyG',
        function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetAllSamplesByStatusUser')
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.greeting = data;

                });
        }

);
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

**sample of json that i'm reading**

```
[{"Sample":{"sampleid":1,"barcode":"129076","createdat":"2015-01-02T00:00:00","createdby":6,"statusid":3},"Status":"Report Generation","FirstName":"Clint","LastName":"Reid"},{"Sample":{"sampleid":2,"barcode":"850314","createdat":"2015-06-15T00:00:00","createdby":7,"statusid":3},"Status":"Report Generation","FirstName":"Kim","LastName":"Mullins"}]
```

**How do I read and display json from a remote source?**

Comment: Just check `console.log(data)`... Try `$scope.greeting = data.data;`.. Read about [__`$http`__](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: also add the error section to also see whats being called if its an error. .error(?), also have a look at this to help your api development,https://www.getpostman.com/ it can also give greta errors/responses if there are any to check your api url is good

Comment: console.log(data) returns nothing

Comment: http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetAllSamplesByStatusUser   returns a bunch of json

Comment: `$http.get` has `then` handler.. not `success`..Try `$http.get('http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetAllSamplesByStatusUser')
   .then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
   });`

Comment: @Rayon, same same.

Comment: I will need a fiddle to play with...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEjp-CG7h4w

Comment: I am in no mood of joking..And someone found that comment useful... Wow!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115876/discussion-between-l-and-rayon).

Comment: I'd look at the network tab of your browser's developer tools and examine what's coming back from that call. It's probably not returning what you think it's returning.

Comment: Just want to make sure, are you getting any response for this request "http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetAllSamplesByStatusUser" when you just enter in into the browser's address bar ?

Comment: @TharsanSivakumar yes i get the correct response back within the browser

Comment: format the json as ng-repeat works on a proper format of array of json.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan here's what the developer tools is showing http://i.imgur.com/8hqVIvb.png

Comment: @Deepanjan example please? i will do exactly as you instruct

Comment: check the link i just posted below

Comment: the plnkr i provided solves your prob i hope so @l--''''''---------''''''''''''..

Comment: Your JSON is wrapped in HTML. You might need to look at how you're returning the data from Web API. Make sure you're using a `JsonResult`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i think that comment is spot on, i've changed this from IEnumerable to IHttpAction in the web api http://i.imgur.com/lcrFAeV.png however, still no luck http://i.imgur.com/eAZeJLo.png  , http://i.imgur.com/rGFYtE2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Refer [**`$http`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) *docs*

- Use `.then` handler instead of `.success` as later is depricated
- Access `data` property of response object as it holds the `data`

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('GbyG',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://thetraveltemple.com/webservices/fetchCountry.php')
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data.data;
      });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="GbyG">
  <table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in greeting.countries">
      <td>{{data.country_name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: tried this on my machine: http://i.imgur.com/Dxe7did.png and got this: http://i.imgur.com/FeYpWtb.png

Comment: You have not included the script you have written/copied...Remove `ng-app` from `body`

Comment: still getting same result http://i.imgur.com/lOBT4GD.png  , http://i.imgur.com/WdQxpqN.png

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetAllSamplesByStatusUser. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:45478' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This is quiet basic error ain't it... Try with the URL I had in my example and update me...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/1MkV3qJ7WupKkNlybZNT?p=preview

you can replace the rest service instead of tag.json in the get call, that i used inorder to test.

Your JSON should come in this format.

```
[{
  "Status": "Report Generation",
  "FirstName": "Clint",
  "LastName": "Reid",
  "Sample": {
    "sampleid": 1,
    "barcode": "129076",
    "createdat": "2015-01-02T00:00:00",
    "createdby": 6,
    "statusid": 3
  }
}, {
  "Status": "Report Generation",
  "FirstName": "Kim",
  "LastName": "Mullins",
  "Sample": {
    "sampleid": 2,
    "barcode": "850314",
    "createdat": "2015-06-15T00:00:00",
    "createdby": 7,
    "statusid": 3
  }

}]
```

Comment: thank you for introducing me to plnkr thats very helpful